# XSLT Add target="_blank" to a URL

Tags: html, xml, sharepoint, xslt

I've created an XSLT file that runs through a SharePoint list to generate a table of resources. One part of it creates a link that goes off site. I'm wanting to have it open in a new window using target="_blank", but I'm unsure of how to do this in the XSLT.

Here's the portion that creates the link:

```
<xsl:element name="a">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="Website"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:text>Visit Website</xsl:text>
</xsl:element>
```

Can anyone shed some light on this for me? I'm fairly new to working with XSLTs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Will it work ?

```
<xsl:element name="a">
<xsl:attribute name="href">
    <xsl:value-of select="Website"/>
</xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:text>Visit Website</xsl:text>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: That did work. I don't now why I didn't think of just putting the text between like that. For whatever reason I was thinking I would have to do something similar to the href attribute [having a value-of tag].  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It's actually much easier than this: you don't need these xsl:element and xsl:attribute instructions at all. Just do

```
<a href="{Website}" target="_blank">Visit Website</a>
```

XSLT can be verbose, but it doesn't have to be!